# Automorphism-conjugacy

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, terminology

If $G$ is a group, we can say $g$ is *automorphism-conjugate* to $f$ if there is a group automorphism $\alpha : G \to G$ such that $g = \alpha(f)$. This is an equivalence relation.

> Is there a standard name for this equivalence relation? Is it a well-studied notion? Does it have some importance somewhere?

Some alternative ways to state this:

- like conjugacy classes, we can talk about automorphism orbits in  group, and I am just asking for the name of / literature on the related equivalence, or equivalence relation.
- $f, g \in G$ are automorphism-conjugate if and only if $f$ and $g$ are actually conjugate in the holomorph of $G$.

I feel like I have encountered this before, but I am not even able to find a name in the literature (I found it a little hard to search for because Google confuses it with e.g. conjugacy *in* automorphism groups, and a range of other things that sound vaguely similar).

I'm thinking about this because I realized that if $G$ is a big homeomorphism group, Rubin's theorem shows that automorphism-conjugacy is a notion between group-theoretic and topological conjugacy (because group automorphisms have to come from topological conjugacies), and these two notions are of great interest to me.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I guess you mean that $g, f$ are fixed group elements here, and that if there is an inner automorphism $\alpha$ mapping $g$ to $f$ then we say that $g$ and $f$ are conjugate -- but what if $\alpha$ is not inner? (I think this is your question). In that case, don't we just say that $g$ and $f$ are in the same automorphic orbit?

Comment: Yes, that's a possible roundabout way of rewording the definition.

Comment: I agree that this is such a simple notion that it may not need a name. Nevertheless, maybe it has one. Some that I considered are "automorphic", "automorphically conjugate", "automorphism-conjugate", "outer-conjugate" (or something in that direction), "externally/holomorphically conjugate" (the elements are conjugate in the holomorph), some being more sensible than others. I'm fine with also not having a name, but this would help look for information on this.

Comment: In the context of Whitehead's algorithm for free groups, this usually goes by the name "automorphically equivalent"

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, I mentioned that above. There are many characterizations of this property.

Comment: [Right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436217/automorphism-conjugacy#comment1123998_436217), sorry.  Actually, I only read the start of [that comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436217/automorphism-conjugacy#comment1123907_436217), and didn't register the mention of the holomorph at the end.  I will delete my comment.

Comment: I did some rewording because of the close vote, because maybe the wording was not optimal, although I don't know whether the vote was about wording or content.

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for, I am specifically interested in the _automorphism problem_. For some reason I only looked for a name of the equivalence relation, rather than searched for the problem directly. Probably this is also where I have encountered it.